# A recurrence relation of the Pell and Negative Pell Equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

In solving for isosceles almost and nearly Pythagorean triples, I have observed that the set of triples:

$$ S_n = \{ (1,1,1), (2,2,3) ,(5,5,7), (12, 12, 17), (29, 29, 41) \dots \}$$

are iso-APTs for odd $n$ and iso-NPTs for even $n$. Moreover, I've observed that the next terms are given by: $$(x+y, x+y, x+2y)$$ where $(x,y)$ is a solution to $x^2-2y^2 = \pm 1$

How can I show that if I have $(x,y)$ as a solution to either signs of $x^2-2y^2 = \pm 1$, then $(x+2y, x+y)$ is a solution to the Pell equation of the opposite sign?

Comment: You mean like $(x+2y)^2-2(x+y)^2=-(x-2y^2)$?

Comment: Yes. Does that hold in general?

Comment: Yes.  $(x+2y)^2-2(x+y)^2=x^2+4xy+4y^2-2x^2-4xy-2y^2=-(x^2-2y^2)$

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725577/when-the-sum-of-squares-of-two-consecutive-integers-is-again-a-perfect-square)

Answer (score 1):

Note the two variable "Special Algebraic Identity"

$$ 0 = (a + 2b)^2 - 2(a + b)^2 + a^2 - 2 b^2 \tag1 $$

which is a special case of the four variable identity

$$ 0 = (ad-bc)^2 - ab(c-d)^2 - (a-b)(ad^2-bc^2). \tag2 $$

In equation $(1)$ replace $a$ with $x$ and $b$ with $y$ to get

$$ (x+2y)^2 - 2(x+y)^2 = -(x^2 - 2y^2). \tag3 $$

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @numbergobbler Thank *you* for the opportunity to add two new identities to my "Special Algebraic Identity" collection.

Comment: I am curious on whether this can be applied to other Pell-like equations. 

I have applied this on the case where $x^2 - 2y^2 = n$ by the way.

Comment: @numbergobbler The Wikipedia aritcle [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) gives much information about the long history of solutions. Does it answer your question?